# Checking dictionary entry to another dictionary, adding if certain key:value pair in entry

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = [{file:2015a, instrument:NES, gain:23}, {file:2015b, instrument:NES, gain:26}, {file:2015d, instrument:NES, gain:25}]

dict2=  [{file:2015a, instrument:NES, gain:3333}, {file:2015c, instrument:PS2, gain:26}, {file:2015d, instrument:NES, gain:4545}]
```

What I'd like to do is take all the dictionary entries from dict2 that use instrument=PS2 and put them in dict1, ignoring all other entries in dict2.

Or just create a new dictionary, dict3, that has all the entries from dict1 that have instrument:NES and all the entries from dict2 that have instrument:PS2.

What's the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: They are lists, not dictionaries..

Answer (score 0):

They are dictionaries within lists.

```
>>> dict1=[{'file':'2015a', 'instrument':'NES', 'gain':23}, {'file':'2015b', 'instrument':'NES', 'gain':26}, {'file':'2015d', 'instrument':'NES', 'gain':25}]
>>> dict2=[{'file':'2015a', 'instrument':'NES', 'gain':3333}, {'file':'2015c', 'instrument':'PS2', 'gain':26}, {'file':'2015d', 'instrument':'NES', 'gain':4545}]
```

**You can use filter() over each list and concat them to get the final output like this:**

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x:x['instrument']=='NES', dict1))+list(filter(lambda x:x['instrument']=='PS2', dict2))
[{'instrument': 'NES', 'gain': 23, 'file': '2015a'}, {'instrument': 'NES', 'gain': 26, 'file': '2015b'}, {'instrument': 'NES', 'gain': 25, 'file': '2015d'}, {'instrument': 'PS2', 'gain': 26, 'file': '2015c'}]
>>>
```

Here are the individual outputs:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x:x['instrument']=='NES', dict1))
[{'instrument': 'NES', 'gain': 23, 'file': '2015a'}, {'instrument': 'NES', 'gain': 26, 'file': '2015b'}, {'instrument': 'NES', 'gain': 25, 'file': '2015d'}]
>>> list(filter(lambda x:x['instrument']=='PS2', dict2))
[{'instrument': 'PS2', 'gain': 26, 'file': '2015c'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are lists, with dictionaries as their elements.

Assuming, you want to append dictionaries from `dict2` to `dict1` if the key `instrument` has the value `PS2`:

```
for d in dict2:
    if d.get('instrument') == 'PS2':
        dict1.append(d)
```

On a different note, `dict[1-2]` are not good names for lists.

**Example:**

```
In [153]: dict1 = [{'file': '2015a', 'instrument': 'NES', 'gain': '23'}, {'file': '2015b', 'instrument': 'NES', 'gain': 26}, {'file': '2015d', 'instrument': 'NES', 'gain': 25}]

In [154]: dict2=  [{'file': '2015a', 'instrument': 'NES', 'gain': 3333}, {'file': '2015c', 'instrument': 'PS2', 'gain': 26}, {'file': '2015d', 'instrument': 'NES', 'gain': 4545}]

In [155]: for d in dict2:
   .....:     if d.get('instrument') == 'PS2':
   .....:         dict1.append(d)
   .....:         

In [156]: dict1
Out[156]: 
[{'file': '2015a', 'gain': '23', 'instrument': 'NES'},
 {'file': '2015b', 'gain': 26, 'instrument': 'NES'},
 {'file': '2015d', 'gain': 25, 'instrument': 'NES'},
 {'file': '2015c', 'gain': 26, 'instrument': 'PS2'}]
```

Comment: Ha, thanks, yeah, just example names and fake list items. Didn't realize they were lists, makes since now and much easier in my brain to deal with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers you could also do:

```
tmp_lst = [i for i in dict2 for k,v in i.items() if (k,v)== ('instrument','PS2')]
print dict1+tmp_lst
```

will return

```
[{'instrument': 'NES', 'gain': '23', 'file': '2015a'}, {'instrument': 'NES', 'gain': '26', 'file': '2015b'}, {'instrument': 'NES', 'gain': '25', 'file': '2015d'}, {'instrument': 'PS2', 'gain': 26, 'file': '2015c'}]
```